# Shopify Script for Fixed Discount of a set price based on tags

Tags: ruby, shopify

Using Shopify Scripts :::
I am trying to achieve the below but getting issue. Could you please let me know how to do this.

$25 off a purchase of $125 or more from the "sale" section. These products have a tag "sale" and are also in a collection "sale" based on that tag.

Looking forward for your quick response.

Great Thanks

Comment: Please state the issue. Please provide the code you are using. Are you using Shopify Plus or normal Shopify subscriptio?

Comment: I am using Shopify Scripts
CAMPAIGNS=[
  #$5 off all items with the sale tag
  ItemCampaign.new(
    AndSelector.new(
      TagSelector.new("sale"),
      ExcludeGiftCartSelector.new,
    ),MoneyDiscount.new(5_00, "5$ off all items on sale",), ),]
CAMPAIGNS.each do |campaign|
  campaign.run(Input.cart) end Output.cart = Input.cart
It is applied to each single item of sale tag, so need to calculate the all sales collection items price in the cart and if their price is greater than $125 then discount would be $25
need solution using shopify scripts or any way in the shopify cart code

Comment: @Hymnz Any updates or solution. Let me know if you have solution for this using any route/way..

Comment: I have had not good success with discounts and Shopify scripts. I did a similar thing to have an effect on checkout. Track products on "sale" using tags, JSON objects and cart.attribute of Shopify cart. It's a round about way but works. If sale condition is satisfied simply lookout for checkout event call and append `?DISCOUNT=<code>` to the checkout url.

Comment: Hello Hymnz, van you please share the code along with the file names where you did te customization etc... Looking forward

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the documentation for Shopify Scripts you'll notice that there is no support for auditing the line item for tags. So you should try the other approach which is proven, and works well.

Look for an item with a compare at price. If you find one, then that typically means the item is on sale. So you can rig your logic to look for items with a compare at price, and if they have one, then determine if the cart has exceeded the $125 in value, and if so, apply your discount.

Comment: I need this to be done either from shopify scripts or core editing, just need the code to work it out

Comment: And that is what my answer gave you mr. The recipe you need. It takes mere minutes to examine the examples for your use case. nothing tricky.

Comment: I am using Shopify Scripts CAMPAIGNS=[ #$5 off all itemswithsale tag ItemCampaign.new( AndSelector.new( TagSelector.new("sale"), ExcludeGiftCartSelector.new, ),MoneyDiscount.new(5_00, "5$ off all items on sale",), ),] CAMPAIGNS.each do |campaign| campaign.run(Input.cart) end Output.cart = Input.cart It is applied to each single item of sale tag, so need to calculate the all sales collection items price in the cart and if their price is greater than $125 then discount would be $25 need solution using shopify scripts or any way in the shopify cart code
Let me know if you have solution or not

Comment: Thanks for that hot tip. I have not used that Tag Selector feature like you did. Cool...

Comment: No Issue if you haven't work with this. 
So let me know if you have solution for this using any of way to achieve it, like customizing the cart code etc... whatever solution you have, I need this to get done asap using any route..

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you the exact code as I don't know the structure of your code. But this is what you need to do.

1. Wherever a product can be added to the cart assign a JavaScript function to check if the product is of "Sale" collection. If yes, add an attribute `cart.attributes.something.something` and keep changing it as and when required.
2. When the checkout mechanism is present in the page, and if your conditions satisfy the Sale discount, take then to `/checkout?DISCOUNT=<CODE>` and click of checkout. It'll automatically apply the discount.